# Using a Dictionary to Replace Values Over a List of Strings

Tags: python, regex, function, string-matching

I am trying to use a dictionary to quickly substitute in incorrect words in each string in a list.

NOTE: I am trying to create a custom function, and the **only solution that I could create was a set of nested "for loops"**, which was ***computationally prohibitive*** considering the actual data I need to manipulate **was over 150,000 in length.**

Consider this:

```py
test_combine = ["cat", "dog", "Hello", "Johnny", "You",
 "123_happy_goose", "123_happy", "45_goose", "45_lamegoose"]
```

Now in reality, these are addresses, but I created this sample problem. I want to replace these with a dictionary:

```py
replace_dic = {"cat":"dog", "_happy_":"_sad_", "_goose\\b":"duck", "Johnny":"john"}
```

My file currently only uses underscores, and I use them when matching to ensure only certain cases are replaced. Example: If I want to change only `happy` if it is a middle word, I would `re.sub` with `"_happy_"` so that only `"123_happy_goose"` is changed and not `"123_happy."`

Ideally, the correct function would return

```py
["dog", "dog", "Addition", "Hello", "john", "You",
 "123_sad_goose", "123_happy", "45_duck", "45_lamegoose"]
```

Comment: so have you tried something for it?

Answer (score 0):

```
def replace(lst,dct):
    ar = []
    for i in lst:
        for k in dct.keys():
            i=i.replace(k,dct[k])
        ar.append(i)
    return ar

test_combine = ["cat", "dog", "Hello", "Johnny", "You",
 "123_happy_goose", "123_happy", "45_goose", "45_lamegoose"]

replace_dic = {"cat":"dog", "_happy_":"_sad_", "_goose\\b":"duck", "Johnny":"john"}

print(replace(test_combine,replace_dic))
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the post, I had successfully created a function using two nested for loops. I was searching for a more efficient way to create this